# How to delete a deployment manager profile that was partially created?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I was creating a deployment manager profile in IBM WebSphere. I stopped it while it was creating using ctrl+C. When I ran the command `manageprofiles.sh -listProfiles`, it did not return any `profiles([])`. Then I tried creating the profile with the same name but I got a message stating a profile with the same name already exists. So I tried running the `manageprofiles -delete` command with the partially created profile name only to find that the profile does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the partially created directory from `WAS_ROOT/profiles/` and run the `manageprofiles -validateAndUpdateRegistry` command. You should be fine then.

> `-validateAndUpdateRegistry`
>       Checks all of the profiles that are listed in the profile registry to see if the profiles are present on the file system. Removes any
>   missing profiles from the registry. Returns a list of the missing
>   profiles that were deleted from the registry.

See [manageprofiles command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/rxml_manageprofiles.html?lang=en)

Comment: It returned -> list of profiles that are not valid: dmgr01. dmgr01 was the name of the partially created profile.

Comment: @kad that should be fine. And that operation should update the registry so you should be able to create new dmgr01 profile now.

Comment: For Windows users: if you cannot delete the directory, open the task manager and kill the java processes. Then try again deleting the directory. Worked for me. Thanks for the answer @gas